# How to find index of the last non-empty element in a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell-array

I initialized a very long cell array(vector?)

```
train_labels = cell(16218, 1);
```

These will be populated using files from 50 different folders, to make sure that the files are indexed in the right location, I need the index of the last cell array that was written to.

For example after reading one folder, the index in `train_labels` had reached `5406`. Now to read the images from the next folder they must be saved to the next index that is `5407`. To make that work I need to find the location of the last non-empty array in `train_labels`.

Since the simple `find(train_labels,1,'last')` does not work on cell arrays. I used `cellfun` but that is also not working. This is what I tried:

```
cellfun(@find, train_labels, 'last')
Error using cellfun
Input #3 expected to be a cell array, was char instead.
```

Would appreciate any guidance on how to get the last index of the cell array.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `cellfun` with `'isempty'` option -

```
last_non_empty_index = find(~cellfun('isempty',train_labels),1,'last')
```

You can also use `cellfun(@isempty..)`, but I believe that must be slower. This has been discussed in detail in this [Undocumented MATLAB Blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost).

`isempty` is a built-in and as such appears to be an optimized implementation. Other built-ins that are available in 2014A version of `cellfun` are - `'isreal'`, `'islogical'`, `'length'`, `'ndims'`, `'prodofsize'`, `'size'`, `'isclass'`. I am hoping that these are fast implementations as well. More info on these are available in its official documentation that can be accessed with `>> help cellfun`.

Comment: Great tip. I had forgotten all about the special code paths.  I always assumed `bsxfun` also had special code paths to make common ops like `plus` and `times` fast, but it only takes function handles.  I'd wager that it still has special cases for the functions listed it the help and generic handling for user-specified handles.

Comment: @chappjc Yeah in fact they got few other built-ins if you look inside `cellfun` source code! Must be interesting to try out!

Comment: Thank you. That did it. just out of curiosity what is the difference between ``find(~cellfun...`` and ``find(@cellfun...``?

Comment: @FarazKhan `cellfun('isempty'..)` finds all the empty ones, so negation (~) finds all the non empty ones. `..1,'last'` gets us the last match. Hope this makes sense!