# Length of longest repeating string within a longer string

Tags: string, matlab, substring

I'm working with a series of long strings (e.g., `'ABAABBFGGBHHSFAFDAFDAFDBB'`), that have different lengths. For each string, I'd like to find the length of the longest consecutive occurrences of a specific substring (for instance `'AFD'`, for which the answer in the above example is `3`). Any elegant way of achieving this with MATLAB ?

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular expression:

```
str = 'AFDABAABBFGGBHHSFAFDAFDAFDBB'; %// note: two occurrences of repeated 'AFD'
substr = 'AFD';                       %// sought substring 
r = regexp(str, ['(' substr ')+'], 'match');
lengths = cellfun(@numel, r)/numel(substr);
result = max(lengths);
```

You can increase speed using `'length'` instead of `@numel`, as [suggested by Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618078/length-of-longest-repeating-string-within-a-longer-string/30618242#comment49305221_30618242):

```
lengths = cellfun('length', r)/numel(substr);
```

In this example,

```
lengths =
     1     3
result =
     3
```

Comment: For some performance boost :  consider using `cellfun('length'..)`, following this [`Undocumented blog post`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost)? Also, listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532342/3293881).

Answer (score 4):

Let the input and search strings be -

```
in_str = 'ABAAAFDAFDBBFGGBHHSFAFDAFDAFDBB'
search_str = 'AFD'
```

We can use [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) to get starting indices for search string in input string and from those detect consecutive groups of search string -

```
idx = strfind(in_str,search_str)
grp_matches = diff(idx)==numel(search_str)
```

So, now we have "islands" of zeros and ones, where the islands of ones represent the presence of consecutive grouped search stings. Next up, we need to find the islands lengths and the maximum island length would be the desired output -

```
df1 = diff([0 grp_matches 0]) %// Perform differentiation of matches
```

The ending of islands would be indicated by "-1" in differentiation result and "1" would denote the starting of those islands. So, `(find(df1==-1) - find(df1==1))+1` would be the island lengths. The final output would be the `max` of it -

```
out = max(find(df1==-1) - find(df1==1))+1
```

---

**Summing up the discussion**, the entire code could be made into a *compact* version like so -

```
df1 = diff([0 diff(strfind(in_str,search_str))==numel(search_str) 0])
out = max(find(df1==-1) - find(df1==1))+1
```

Comment: Does it work for all cases? for eg: - `'ABAAAFDAFDBBFGGBHHSFAFDAFDAFDBB'`

Comment: haha! I too tried similar approach much similar to that previous edit and wasn't able to generalize it. You did great :) +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't yet know what the content of the string is that you are looking for:

1. Compare the first half of the string to the second half (`length: N/2`), if equal, done. Longest string found.
2. Else: conduct a **bitwise autocorrelation of subsamples**. Steps:
3. compare a windowed version (substring) of the total string of length `M < N/2` by conducting a bitwise autocorrelation and run an `AND` on the result of each frame. If the selected subwindow is in there, the `AND` will result in a `1` for the parts of the string where it is located and you're done, you found the longest reoccurring substring.
4. if **#3** didn't return a positive result (**no occurrence**), **decrease** the length **M** of the substring by 1: `M = M - 1` and repeat **#3** while no occurrence found and `M > 0`.
5. If there is absolutely **no reoccurrence of any substring** you'll know once `M = 0` .